# Xamarin Android TabLayout adding fragments to ViewPager instead of layouts

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

I am new to Android development and decided to make a tabLayout in xamarin android. I got it all working, but the only problem is; my ViewPager is showing xml Layouts and not fragments.

I can't do anything with a button inside the layout now, I have tried different things with adapters etc. but can't seem to get it working.

The TabLayout is custom made which contains a LinearLayout and a HorizontalScrollView.

My MainActivity which adds the whole tabLayout:

```
 public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Api getapi = new Api();
        // getapi.GetApi();

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);           

        FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        SlidingTabsFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsFragment();
        transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);

        transaction.Commit();

    }



}
```

My Fragment with the adapter and ViewPager (just inflating the layouts ugly atm):

```
    public class SlidingTabsFragment : Fragment
{
    private SlidingTabScrollView mSlidingTabScrollView;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_sample, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        mSlidingTabScrollView = view.FindViewById<SlidingTabScrollView>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);
        mViewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.Adapter = new SamplePagerAdapter();

        mSlidingTabScrollView.ViewPager = mViewPager;
    }

    public class SamplePagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();

        public SamplePagerAdapter()
            : base()
        {
            items.Add("Home");
            items.Add("Surfboard kopen");
            items.Add("Surfboard customize");
            items.Add("Nieuwsbrief");
            items.Add("Contact");
            items.Add("FAQ");
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }

        public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object obj)
        {
            return view == obj;
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
        {
            if (position == 4)
            {
                View view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Contact, container, false);
                container.AddView(view);

                return view;
            }

            if (position == 0)
            {
                View view = LayoutInflater.From(container.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Home, container, false);
                container.AddView(view);

                return view;
            }

        }

        public string GetHeaderTitle(int position)
        {
            return items[position];
        }

        public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object obj)
        {
            container.RemoveView((View)obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#E2E2E2"
        android:id="@+id/sample_main_layout">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

fragment_sample.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/backgroundd"
        android:src="@drawable/SurfChicks"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:alpha="0.35" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Smoothboard_Stylers_App.SlidingTabScrollView
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Scrollview:

```
namespace Smoothboard_Stylers_App
{
    public class SlidingTabScrollView : HorizontalScrollView
    {
        private const int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
        private const int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
        private const int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

        private int mTitleOffset;

        private int mTabViewLayoutID;
        private int mTabViewTextViewID;

        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

        private static SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

        private int mScrollState;
        public interface TabColorizer
        {
            int GetIndicatorColor(int position);
            int GetDividerColor(int position);
        }

        public SlidingTabScrollView(Context context) : this(context, null) { }

        public SlidingTabScrollView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : this(context, attrs, 0) { }

        public SlidingTabScrollView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle)
            : base(context, attrs, defaultStyle)
        {
            //Disable the scroll bar
            HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;

            //Make sure the tab strips fill the view
            FillViewport = true;
            this.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(0xE5, 0xE5, 0xE5)); //Gray color

            mTitleOffset = (int)(TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);

            mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
            this.AddView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        }

        public TabColorizer CustomTabColorizer
        {
            set { mTabStrip.CustomTabColorizer = value; }
        }

        public int[] SelectedIndicatorColor
        {
            set { mTabStrip.SelectedIndicatorColors = value; }
        }

        public int[] DividerColors
        {
            set { mTabStrip.DividerColors = value; }
        }

        public ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener OnPageListener
        {
            set { mViewPagerPageChangeListener = value; }
        }

        public ViewPager ViewPager
        {
            set
            {
                mTabStrip.RemoveAllViews();

                mViewPager = value;
                if (value != null)
                {
                    value.PageSelected += value_PageSelected;
                    value.PageScrollStateChanged += value_PageScrollStateChanged;
                    value.PageScrolled += value_PageScrolled;
                    PopulateTabStrip();
                }
            }
        }

        void value_PageScrolled(object sender, ViewPager.PageScrolledEventArgs e)
        {
            int tabCount = mTabStrip.ChildCount;

            if ((tabCount == 0) || (e.Position < 0) || (e.Position >= tabCount))
            {
                //if any of these conditions apply, return, no need to scroll
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.OnViewPagerPageChanged(e.Position, e.PositionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.GetChildAt(e.Position);

            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null ? (int)(e.Position * selectedTitle.Width) : 0);

            ScrollToTab(e.Position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null)
            {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.OnPageScrolled(e.Position, e.PositionOffset, e.PositionOffsetPixels);
            }

        }

        void value_PageScrollStateChanged(object sender, ViewPager.PageScrollStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            mScrollState = e.State;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null)
            {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.OnPageScrollStateChanged(e.State);
            }
        }

        void value_PageSelected(object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.ScrollStateIdle)
            {
                mTabStrip.OnViewPagerPageChanged(e.Position, 0f);
                ScrollToTab(e.Position, 0);

            }

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null)
            {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.OnPageSelected(e.Position);
            }
        }

        private void PopulateTabStrip()
        {
            PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.Adapter;

            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.Count; i++)
            {
                TextView tabView = CreateDefaultTabView(Context);
                tabView.Text = ((SlidingTabsFragment.SamplePagerAdapter)adapter).GetHeaderTitle(i);
                tabView.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
                tabView.Tag = i;
                tabView.Click += tabView_Click;
                mTabStrip.AddView(tabView);
            }

        }

        void tabView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextView clickTab = (TextView)sender;
            int pageToScrollTo = (int)clickTab.Tag;
            mViewPager.CurrentItem = pageToScrollTo;
        }

        private TextView CreateDefaultTabView(Android.Content.Context context)
        {
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            textView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Sp, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
            textView.Typeface = Android.Graphics.Typeface.DefaultBold;

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Honeycomb)
            {
                TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
                Context.Theme.ResolveAttribute(Android.Resource.Attribute.SelectableItemBackground, outValue, false);
                textView.SetBackgroundResource(outValue.ResourceId);
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.IceCreamSandwich)
            {
                textView.SetAllCaps(true);
            }

            int padding = (int)(TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
            textView.SetPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

            return textView;
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();

            if (mViewPager != null)
            {
                ScrollToTab(mViewPager.CurrentItem, 0);
            }
        }

        private void ScrollToTab(int tabIndex, int extraOffset)
        {
            int tabCount = mTabStrip.ChildCount;

            if (tabCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabCount)
            {
                //No need to go further, dont scroll
                return;
            }

            View selectedChild = mTabStrip.GetChildAt(tabIndex);
            if (selectedChild != null)
            {
                int scrollAmountX = selectedChild.Left + extraOffset;

                if (tabIndex > 0 || extraOffset > 0)
                {
                    scrollAmountX -= mTitleOffset;
                }

                this.ScrollTo(scrollAmountX, 0);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks like:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQNrz.png)

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you please show the design image how it looks ??

Comment: Added the design @stylishCoder

Comment: From my experience it's a very bad idea to have a `viewpager` inside `fragment`.

Comment: By the way, I don't understand what you mean by `showing xml Layouts and not fragments`

Comment: I am inflating layouts at the InstantiateItem method. So it shows the right layout for each tab, but I can't handle button events like that because it is just a layout that I am inflating without a fragment connected to it. @misho

Comment: Ok, got it, I'll write a solution in a minute

Comment: Awesome! looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead:

Create fragments and inflate xml in their `OnCreate` method.

Your `FragmentPagerAdapter` should look like this:

```
public class MenuPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private string[] Titles;
    private List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> _fragments;
    Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager _fragmentManager;

    public MenuPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm, string[] titles)
        : base(fm)
    {
        Titles = titles;
        _fragments = new List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>();
        _fragments.Add(new HomeFragment());
        _fragments.Add(new SurfboardKopenFragment());
        _fragments.Add(new NieuwsbriefFragment());
        _fragments.Add(new ContactFragment()); // and etc.
    }

    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        return _fragments[position];
    }

    public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
    {

       return new Java.Lang.String(Titles[position]);
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { Titles.Length; } // amount of fragments you have = Amount of Tab titles.
    }

    public override int GetItemPosition(Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
    {
        return PositionNone;
    }

    public Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetFragment(int position)
    {
        return  _fragments[position];
    }
}
```

Then initialize viewpager in your activity or fragment.

```
    private MenuPagerAdapter adapter;
    private CustomViewPager pager;
    void InitAdapter()
        {
           string[] titles = new []
                        { 
                            "Home",
                            "..."
                        }; 
            pager = FindViewById<CustomViewPager>(Resource.Id.pager);
            pager.EnableTouchEvents(true);
            adapter = new MenuPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, titles); 
            var pageMargin = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 4, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
            pager.OffscreenPageLimit = titles.Length;//amount of fragments you want to stay in memory(for faster tab change) 
            pager.PageMargin = pageMargin;
            pager.AddOnPageChangeListener(this);
            pager.Adapter = adapter;
            pager.CurrentItem = 0;
        }
```

Implement `Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener` in your fragment or activity:

```
public void OnPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
    {
    }

    public void OnPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
    {
        // Do anything you like when page scrolls
    }

    public void OnPageSelected(int position)
    { // Do anything you like when tab is clicked. Position is clicked Tab position.
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Important Note:
You should use `ChildFragmentManager` here `adapter = new MenuPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, this, pager);` instead of `SupportFragmentManager` if you insist to use `viewpager` in fragment.

Important Advice:
Completely remove `SlidingTabFragment` and move everything from there to MainActivity.

**Edit:** Due to some copy/paste mistakes in code, decided to creat sample project with PagerSlidingTabStrip. Have fun:
[PagerSlidingTabStrip-Sample](https://github.com/marabdeliarsena/PagerSlidingTabStrip-Sample)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help :) But I am getting some errors; I created the MenuPagerAdapter but he gives an error at : base(fm). Not sure where fm is standing for.

Comment: : base(fm) is passing `fragmentManager` to parent class. Can you tell me what is the error?

Comment: P.S. you need `support v4` installed from components or nuget packages.

Comment: The type or namescape name 'fm' could not be found.

Comment: got Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 in my references

Comment: sorry for a late reply. It looks like a copy/paste mistake. can you make a screenshot, please? 

either you missed something while copying the code or I did.

Comment: Sorry for mine too ;) this is the error: http://prntscr.com/b97gjv as you can see like half the file is red haha. Can we maybe communicate via something else because this isn't the most efficient, maybe skype? My scrollview already takes care of the onpagescrolled etc. I will add the code too.

Comment: @RemcoA that's my skype id: marabdeliarsena

Comment: Added you. Hope to talk to you soon!

Comment: @arsena the pagerslidingtabstrip-sample just shows white view